# Why is negative margin not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you click 'Resume' some text comes in from the left. This is because I gave negative margin to the text initially.

But negative margin of `intro_page` gives no effect.

What I want is that:

1. When I click `resume_page`, text of resume should come in from left (this works) and text of `intro_page` should go out to the right (this doesn't work).

   Negative margin of `intro_page` doesn't seem to be working. Why is that?
2. Initially, page should be empty except the two links. Currently, `intro_page` page is shown. `resume_page` is hidden properly, as desired.

In short, everything about `resume_page` works perfectly. I want the exact same things to happen to `intro_page`

```js
function clicked_resume(OnScreen)
{
    var resume = document.getElementById('resume_page');
    if(OnScreen == 1)
    {
        resume.className = '';
        clicked_about(0);
    }
    else if(OnScreen == 0)
    {
        resume.className = 'unseen';
    }
    
}

function clicked_about(OnScreen)
{
   
    var about = document.getElementById('intro_page');
    if(OnScreen == 1)
    {
        about.className = '';
        clicked_resume(0);

    }
    else if(OnScreen == 0)
    {
        about.className = 'unseen';
    }
}
```

```css
#intro_page.unseen{
 display: block;
 margin-right: -200px;
}


#intro_page{
 margin-right: 0px;
 display: block;
 -webkit-transition: margin-right 1.5s ease-in;
 transition: margin-right 1.5s ease-in;
}

#resume_page.unseen{
 display: block;
 margin-left: -600px;
}

#resume_page{
 margin-left: 0px;
 display: block;
 -webkit-transition: margin-left 1.0s ease-in;
 transition: margin-left 1.0s ease-in;
}
```

```html
 <h2 class="title_bar">
<ul>
     
 <li><span onclick = "clicked_about(1)">About</span></li>
 <li><span onclick="clicked_resume(1)">Resume</span></li>
</ul>
     
</h2> 

 
<div id="intro_page" class="unseen">
 <p id="intro_main_text"> I enjoy reading, swimming, jogging, painting and exploring. </p>
 <figure class="intro_pic1">
     <img src="img/award.jpg" alt="Receiving Award" height="50" />
     <figcaption>Award 2015</figcaption>
 </figure>
</div>

<div id="resume_page" class="unseen">
 <p>My resume</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `position: relative` and `right` instead of `margin-right`. It's more reliable since it doesn't take the element's position into account when positioning other elements, like `margin` does. For bonus points you could even use `transform: translate` instead of `right`.

```js
function clicked_resume(OnScreen)
{
    var resume = document.getElementById('resume_page');
    if(OnScreen == 1)
    {
        resume.className = '';
        clicked_about(0);
    }
    else if(OnScreen == 0)
    {
        resume.className = 'unseen';
    }
    
}

function clicked_about(OnScreen)
{
   
    var about = document.getElementById('intro_page');
    if(OnScreen == 1)
    {
        about.className = '';
        clicked_resume(0);

    }
    else if(OnScreen == 0)
    {
        about.className = 'unseen';
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#intro_page.unseen{
    display: block;
 right: -100%;
}


#intro_page{
 position: relative;
    right: 0px;
 display: block;
 -webkit-transition: right 1.5s ease-in;
 transition: right 1.5s ease-in;
}

#resume_page.unseen{
 display: block;
 left: -600px;
}

#resume_page{
 position: relative;
    left: 0px;
 display: block;
 -webkit-transition: left 1.0s ease-in;
 transition: left 1.0s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title_bar">
<ul>
     
 <li><span onclick = "clicked_about(1)">About</span></li>
 <li><span onclick="clicked_resume(1)">Resume</span></li>
</ul>
     
</h2> 

 
<div id="intro_page" class="unseen">
 <p id="intro_main_text"> I enjoy reading, swimming, jogging, painting and exploring. </p>
 <figure class="intro_pic1">
     <img src="img/award.jpg" alt="Receiving Award" height="50" />
     <figcaption>Award 2015</figcaption>
 </figure>
</div>

<div id="resume_page" class="unseen">
 <p>My resume</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You. Can you please solve the Problem 2. The negative margin of `intro_page` should make it hidden initially (just like `resume_page` is hidden). However, `about_page` is seen.

Comment: Somehow, I still see `intro_page` every time. Basically, `intro_page` is always visible; it just moves a little to the right. Is there any way I can hide it until 'About' is clicked?

Comment: @Matt Do you want it to slide in from the left like the resume page? If so, instead of using `right`, use a negative `left` value and a transition on `left`. Alternatively, use a negative `transform: translate` value and transition on `transform`. Sorry for the iterative process here, I'm just not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The effect I wanted is that `resume_page` comes  left-->right and `intro_page` comes right-->left. In both cases, the content is hidden initially and appears only on click. From what I understand, the right-->left effect is not possible using margin or translate. Is there any other way I can achieve this effect?

Comment: @Matt Thanks for clarifying. In that case I would give your containing element (in this case the body) an `overflow-x` value of `hidden`, and your `intro_page` a `right` value of `-100%`. See updated example.

Answer (score 2):

The Reason is that in CSS the elements are laid from left to right, margin-right would never work as you wish.

Just Modifying your CSS like this, it will work as a charm.

```
 body {
   overflow:hidden
}

#intro_page.unseen{
    transform: translateX(120%);
    transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}
#intro_page{
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}

#resume_page.unseen{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}

#resume_page{
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}
```

Hint: for better performance in animation always use translations instead of position, margin, width...

http://jsfiddle.net/wgsy6ufx/1/

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in [this guide](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/), left and right negative margins don't behave the same : negative `margin-left` pulls the **styled** element towards the left, while negative `margin-right` pulls the **adjacent right** element towards the styled element. It doesn't move the styled element itself.

If you want to achieve your output, use `position: relative` and the `left` property to position your intro div in the far right : see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9qvjket/).

Answer (score 0):

For anybody having similar issues...what worked for me was to change the width to auto instead of 100%.